# For loops and layout support in express.js template engine

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine

I come from a PHP background and I've used frameworks such as CakePHP and Laravel and it is quite easy to work with layouts and views in all of them.
And the possibility of using PHP inside those template engines provide a way to do things such as:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++){ ?>
    <td>demo</td>
<? } ?>
```

Now, starting with Node and express.js I found out template engines seems quite basic here. I've tried hjs, hogan, swig, mustache, handlebars... none of them offers both :

- Layout support (templates and views)
- A way to do loops like the one I named before.

Am I missing something? Am I asking for too much?
Which one would you recommend me?

Comment: Have you tried **EJS**?

Comment: @ArunGhosh nop, but it seems [it requires another plugin for layout support](https://github.com/Soarez/express-ejs-layouts), right?

Comment: Have a look http://www.embeddedjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the template engines for Javascript take the philosophical view that it's better to enforce a fairly strict separation between logic and presentation, meaning that the complexity of code/logic allowed in the template is deliberately limited. For a quick overview of this topic, see http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/the-new-hot-thing-in-web-development-client-side-templating-languages.html (it's about client-side templating, but since it's Javascript, a lot of those same template languages are the ones popular in node.js / Express). This idea of logicless templates exists in the PHP world as well, it's just not as common.

For a more academic treatment of this subject, see this paper: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf. (The author is also the author of a popular template engine for Java called [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/).) The author makes a lot of good points, and in general I agree with the idea of logicless templates, but there are times when it can be inconvenient and I find myself more on the fence about it...see [this link](http://www.simple-is-better.org/template/) for some further considerations. Obviously there are also those who want to be able to anything from a template (as you can in PHP) and believe it's fine to rely on the self-restraint of the programmer not to put too much code in the view, which is where template engines like [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) come in.

Having said all that, it's important to note that what you want to achieve is possible in Handlebars (which is one of the "logicless" languages) and probably many of the others you tried as well. To do it in Handlebars, you'd need to create a custom helper. This might be what you're looking for:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/handlebars-helper-repeat

Example usage:

```
{{#repeat 10}}
   {{> button }}
{{/repeat}}
```

You could also extend it to be able to support arguments to be able to control the starting number or increment, although that would probably be getting into logic that might be better done in the JS code (according to the Handlebars philosophy) while preparing the data for the template.

With regard to layouts, the closest thing in Handlebars (which is the template engine I'm most familiar with) is partials. This link provides a good introduction to those: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers.

Personally I'm a big fan of the template language in an awesome framework (built on Express) called [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/). Its template language is similar to Handlebars, but comes with a couple of handy extensions - just enough to make it a bit more convenient to use without allowing too much logic to creep into the template. Unfortunately I don't think there's a standalone version of it (i.e. you have to use the full Derby framework), but you could create custom helpers in Handlebars to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: P.S. Derby supports layouts, and also supports [components](http://derbyjs.com/0.5/views#components).

Comment: If you're interested in considering client-side solutions as well, you may also want to check out [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), if you haven't already (but my favorite is still Derby).